# Send email through HTML using php

Tags: php, html

Hey guys I am working on a personal project and building a form to send an email but I am getting 404 not found. The file is present (sendmail.php) and is linked to the form.
This is my HTML code:

```
       <form action="sendmail.php" method="post">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-input"
              placeholder="Name"
              name="name"
              required
            />
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-input"
              placeholder="Email"
              name="email"
              required
            />
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-input"
              placeholder="Subject"
              name="subject"
              required
            />
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <textarea
              calss="form-input"
              placeholder="Message"
              name="message"
              required
            ></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <button type="submit" class="more-btn">Send Message</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

this is my php code

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
  <title>PHP mail script</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type"
        content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
 </head>
 <body>
  <?php
  //3 line of code to retrieve the form data sent   "post" 
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $subject=$_POST['subject'];
    $message=$_POST['message'];
    

/*creation of the $msg variable and
 supplementally adding  details to it.*/
    $msg="EMAIL SENT FROM WEBSITE:\r\n " ;
    $msg.="Sender Name: $name\r\n ";
    $msg.="Sender E-mail: $email\r\n ";
    $msg.="Subject: $message\r\n ";
    $msg.="Message: $message\r\n ";
    

    $to="mike558212@gmail.com";   //were the email  sent to.
    $subject=$subject;   // subject should the email display
    $mailheaders="From: $email\r\n";  // email of the sender


    $formsent=mail($to, $subject, $msg, $mailheaders); //send the email
    if ($formsent)
     {
      echo "<p style= 'background-color:green;color:white;'> Form Received</p>";
     }
     else
     {
      echo "<p style='color:red;'> The form has not been sent !</p>";
     }
     ?>


    <p>Detail of form!<br />
       <?php
       echo  $msg;
       ?>

       </p>of
   <p><a href="index.html">go back</a></p>

 </body>
</html>
```

I deployed this to netlify and I am keep getting /sendmail.php 404 but the php file is there.

Comment: Nothing in your question gives us any hints as to why your HTTP server can't resolve `/sendmail.php` to the URL you think it should resolve to. We know nothing about the hosting package your selected with netlify or how you've configured it. This seems to be a problem better suited to netlify's customer service than to Stackoverflow.

Comment: Do you have a webserver setup and running locally or are you directly loading `index.html` in the browser?

Comment: Directly loading index.html in the browser

Comment: Not a fix but please note that the [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: any ideas? talked with netlify and they said all good on their side.